# Highcharts JS: barchart select the only selected bar without the rest in series

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to inactive and set the gray color in all the rest of the unselected bars in the bar chart of `highcharts` JS, but the problem here is when I select a bar in the first serie for example, all the rest connected bars are selected on the rest of series, I want to select only the selected bar in the selected serie, and inactive all the rest of bars.

picture of the problem :

[image]

what I want to do :

[image]

the code in [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/bar-basic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to achieve it by using the `mouseOver` & `mouseOut` callbacks and by updating the other points.

The important thing - we need to set the redraw flag as false in the `point.update` config to avoid the many redraws in the loops but trigger it only once.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/yd9ex6v2/

```
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      states: {
        inactive: {
          opacity: 1
        }
      },
      point: {
        events: {
          mouseOver() {
            const chart = this.series.chart;

            chart.series.forEach(s => {
              s.points.forEach(p => {
                if (p.id !== this.id) {
                  p.update({
                    color: 'grey'
                  }, false, false)
                }
              })
            });

            chart.redraw();
          },
          mouseOut() {
            const chart = this.series.chart;

            chart.series.forEach(s => {
              s.points.forEach(p => {
                p.update({
                  color: s.color
                }, false, false)
              })
            });
            chart.redraw();
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.point.events.mouseOut

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Point#update